# Tool for Monitoring WCF Service

Tags: wcf

Is there any third party tools available to Monitoring `WCF` Service?

I have created `WCF` Service with 5 Methods (`OperationContract`s) and Hosted in `IIS`.
Does there any tool available to specify how many times each method was called and what is Request and Response of the each call ? (Similar to `SQL` server profiler).

Comment: What's wrong with WCF tracing ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx

Comment: @DavidBrabant, I know WCF Tracing will give complete info. But i just want know like how many times the individual operation get called. AppFabric tool provide Dashboard which will do complete monitoring also supports historical data..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use standart tracing and diagnostic tool for WCF, and work with .svclogs using SvcTraceViewer.exe application.
If you host under IIS, use AppFabric. It a great tool, when you can easily manage the settings of your services, including tracing and diagnostic. There is a nice article about using it http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=771

Answer (score 0):

The AppFabric Dashboard provides a centralized gateway to view and manage the health of WF and WCF services deployed locally or to a server farm. It exposes real-time data from the Persistence database and historic data from the Monitoring database, and it allows you to “drill down” to examine instance and WCF Call metrics in greater detail.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677236(v=azure.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677236%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

AppFabric helps to monitor WCF service like How many time the operation is invoked, Errors/ Faults and also supports historical data.